# Service Application Clubbing SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: service-applications

We planned All Service Application under a single app pool.

which is best place for to modify the app pool name(best practice) CA or IIS(Please tel me the steps) ?

if i create a new app pool name and map it for 5 service application but identity is one account for a app pool name

my question here is , at present all service applicaton carry individual app pool name so after clubbing into a single app pool name what happend other unwanted app pools ?

Please assit on this

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a few Powershell commands that might be useful to you.
Check [Application Pool name IIS 7.5 On SharePoint Server 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20109/application-pool-name-iis-7-5-on-sharepoint-server-2010)

I would say, don't modify anything directly on IIS. Either use the SharePoint Powershell SnapIn cmdlets, or use the CA.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All changes directly in IIS is unsupported.
You usually create a new (web) application pool if you have a new security boundary. For example one account for internet and another one for extranet.
App pools tend to hog memory as well, so if they use the same account it makes sense to create one shared application pool in SharePoint CA or PowerShell. 
After you create it set it for the web applications in question either in CA or again PowerShell