# Application Pool name IIS 7.5 On SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: application-pool

Application Pool Name is IIS is in GUID format in IIS and ****How to get name any powershell command ?****

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationPool |  select name,id, ProcessAccountName

Get-SPServiceApplicationPool |  format-list
```

You might see some Aplication Pools listed in here, and showing up on SharePoint DropDowns, that have actually been deleted already.
You can remove them with

```
Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "My Application Pool To Remove"
```

If you want to change the service account, try

```
Set-SPServiceApplicationPool "My Application Pool To Change" -Account $account
```